# Abrir la Chrome App desde link en web

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando abrir la App de Chrome desde una página web, pero no encuentro la manera.

Todas las soluciones que he probado parecen estar obsoletas. ¿Alguien sabe cómo se hace?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien le sirve, ya conseguí hacerlo:

- En terminales iOS:

`window.location.href = "googlechromes://yoururl";`

- En terminales Android:

`window.location.href = "intent://yoururl#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end;";`

Un saludo,

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a abrir la liga para descargar la App "Chrome" desde la playstore, solo crea un

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome">
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Vendría genial que explicaras lo que hace tu código tanto para el OP como para personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Creo que no me expliqué bien en el enunciado. Me refería a abrir la App de Chrome para asegurarse que la página se visualiza en Chrome. En mi caso era para un desarrollo que funcionaba solo en Crome, si estaba por ejemplo en el Samsung internet browser o en Safari, quería que al pulsar sobre el enlace se me abriese en Chrome, en vez de en Safari o Samsung.